# IBM Rational Software Architect .fileTableLock (Отказано в доступе.)

Tags: eclipse, ibm

При установке IBM RSA 9.0 выскакивает ошибка

> ---
>
> Invalid Configuration Location
>
> ---
>
> Locking is not possible in the directory "D:\IBM\RSA_SETUP\InstallerImage_win32_win32_x86_64\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi". A common reason is that the file system or Runtime Environment does not support file locking for that location. Please choose a different location, or disable file locking passing "-Dosgi.locking=none" as a VM argument. 
>   D:\IBM\RSA_SETUP\InstallerImage_win32_win32_x86_64\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager.fileTableLock (Отказано в доступе.)
>
> ---
>
> ОК
>
> ---

Права файлу задал полный доступ и для админа и для пользователей как рекомендует [ресурс](http://osify.com/2013/01/windows-8-eclipse-issue-invalid-configuration-location/#.VxJpHfmLS70) но не помогло :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прикол, убрал атрибут "только для чтения" и проблема решилась!